# question + と言うと

Tags: particle-と, phrases

Usually Tomo isn't that bad, but he blew me away here. I seem to be well out of my depth trying to get a handle on what's going on in this sentence:

> まぁいい声って言うよりも**これだけいつも**と違う声を出すと、**どちらかというと**面白い声に聞こえますが、いつも同じ声を聞いていると飽きてしまうかもしれないので今日は違う人のpodcastを聴いている気分で、新鮮な気分で、聞いてください。

http://ruby-s.net/2020/08/20/script-%e3%80%90episode093%e3%80%91/

My interpretation is roughly:

> Since, rather than saying "that voice is meh", if I use a different voice than my usual, they might be able to ask which is interesting but if I always use the same voice, one might get tired of it, today ....

This seems to be a bit of a run on sentence and the part after が isn't that bad.

これだけいつもと I'm not clear on this construction. It seems like "only this, the usual", then compared to a different voice.

Then I haven't seen a question bundled with と言うと. I think he's speculating on what a listener might ask. But I don't see how it links to the following 面白い。。。

Without forcing you to listen to it, Tomo is speaking in a deeper voice (or has done some post to lower his voice) in this episode.

Comment: I don't think "run-on" is a thing in Japanese grammar. It is a concept peculiar to languages with strict punctuation rules.

Comment: @EddieKal Well, if by *run-on* someone means a sentence that just rambles or goes on and on and thus loses/obscures the thread of what's being said, certainly that's possible in Japanese.  But, this is definitely not a run-on sentence even under my interpretation of "run-on".

Comment: I'm not sure where your *question* (of the title) is in this quote.  これだけいつも isn't a question.  いつも means "whenever" or, in this context, "my usual [voice]".  どちらかというと means "whichever you consider" and looks a bit more like a question than これだけいつも but it's a fixed phrase akin to "whichever" in English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- いい声 is "cool voice", not "meh voice". When it refers to a male voice, it typically refers to a low-frequency, dandy voice. Note that いい always means "good" rather than "not necessary" when it restrictively modifies the following noun.
- This 面白い is "funny" rather than "interesting".
- This これだけ is "this much", not "only this". It modifies (いつもと)違う. これだけいつもと違う声 literally means "the voice that is as different than usual as this".
- どちらかというと/どっちかというと (literally "to say which") is a common set phrase that means "if anything", "more of", "if I have to choose one", etc.

  > - どちらかというと嬉しかった。 If anything, I was glad.
  > - どっちかというと犬派です。 I'm more of a dog person.

> まぁいい声って言うよりもこれだけいつもと違う声を出すと、どちらかというと面白い声に聞こえますが、いつも同じ声を聞いていると飽きてしまうかもしれないので……
>
> Well, if my voice sounds this different from usual, it would sound more like a funny voice rather than a cool voice, but if you always hear the same voice, you might get tired, so...

Answer (score 2):

The「これだけ」is modifying「いつもと違う」. It seems to describe a degree or amount of difference (ie. how much different from the usual).

There is a hidden question embedded in the「どちらかというと」part. Judging from the context, you can understand it as

> (**面白い声と面白くない声**、)どちらかというと面白い声に聞こえます
>
> If I have to comment whether my voice sounds interesting or not, my voice sounds interesting.

「どちらかというと」is a common expression used when trying to select one thing out multiple options, usually to evaluate its value. It is usually rendered as "if pushed I'd say..." in English.