# What does "どちらかといえばむしろ" mean here?

Tags: meaning

Searching the meaning of まだしも in a Japanese-Japanese dictionary called "三省堂　スーパー大辞林", the following definition (with examples) came up:

> 十分とはいえないが，**どちらかといえばむしろ**。「あやまるなら―，開き直って言い返してきた」「雨ならば，―雪の方がありがたい」

In an attempt to translate the text in bold, I came up with "If anything, rather" which makes no sense. Consulting Google Translate (which, I know, is known to be unreliable sometimes) gave similar results.

I pretty much know what まだしも means after searching different sources, but I still have no idea what どちらかといえばむしろ is.

Comment: どちらかといえば means the same as どちらかというと. This is related: [question + と言うと](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/90939/43676) For むしろ, this might help: [What is the difference between むしろ and かえって?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/57878/43676)

Comment: The version of スーパー大辞林 on my Mac has this easier-to-understand definition: 十分とはいえないが，他のものよりはましであるさま。ともかく。むしろ。「あやまるなら―，開き直って言い返してきた」「雨ならば，―雪の方がありがたい」

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments, this finally clicked for me. どちらかといえば (if anything) + むしろ (A rather than B) = if anything, A rather than B. In hindsight, this was really straightforward.